# Pagination with remote data for the Combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox, pagination

I'm trying to load a combobox with remote data from a SQL database,
Here is the Combobox Code,

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    title: 'Busname',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'myCombobox',
            name: 'busname',
            forceNewStore: true,
            pageSize:10,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: "description",
            valueField: "description",
            mapperId: 'busnamefetch',
            maskRe: /[A-Za-z0-9]/,
            forceSelection: true,
            emptyText: 'Select Bus',
            margin: '15px',
            triggers: {
                clear: {
                    cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
                    handler: function () {
                        this.reset();
                    }
                }
            },
        }]
}
```

I'm mapping this in a seperate mapper file as below,

```
{
key: "busnamefetch",
type: "dServ",
properties: [
    {
        "key": "namespace",
        "value": "Travelmapper"
    },
    {
        "key": "query",
        "value": "selectbusname"
    }]
}
```

**and here,**

```
 {
id: 'selectbusname',
namespace: 'Travelmapper',
statementType: 'CALLABLE',
query: 'SELECT busname as description FROM BusTable order by busname limit 10;'
}
```

now When I try to do a paging in the combobox,The paging tool bar appears and says the showing 1 of... so and so, but the next page thing doesn't work,  what i am Missing please help me here,I have gone through many examples, Couldn't get it.

Comment: Do you adapt the sql statement to the changing limit? At start you have a limit of 0 10 for the first page and on the secound page of 10 10 ... For paged data you must also ensure the totalProperty to be set correctly, so the store knows how many pages exist.

Comment: How to set the total Property for my above example? can you please guide /help me?

Comment: Pagination is combination of UI and back end service by seeing your code we can't say why it is not working because we doesn't have view on back end implementation

Comment: {
`id: 'selectbusname',`
`namespace: 'Travelmapper',`
`statementType: 'CALLABLE',`
`query: 'SELECT busname as description FROM BusTable order by` `busname limit 10;'
`}`
@SuryaPrakashTumma this is the way we communicate to db correct? this is a partial complete code, Can you help me where I'm missing the part. i haven't added any **total** property. where have to add that??

Comment: It is a property of the reader in your store http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.reader.Reader.html#cfg-totalProperty . The server must send it with every request, to let the store know how many pages exist. In your code example the store part is missing, so you must check how it is configured.